# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"exec

Tags: docker

Failed to start a docker with docker compose on MAC (docker desktop)

Here is the output from docker inspect:

```
{
                        "Start": "2019-06-10T13:30:15.2105502Z",
                        "End": "2019-06-10T13:30:15.3055115Z",
                        "ExitCode": -1,
                        "Output": "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"curl\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"
                   }
```

The section in docker compose is:

```
mydocker:
    image: mydocker
    container_name: mydockername
    hostname: mydockerhostname
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
      - confluent
    ports:
      - "8080-8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - myvolume:/pathname
    command:
      - start
      - --insecure
```

I used the docker stop/start, or docker kill/run, but no success.

I was able to use the same docker compose script to launch the container several weeks ago, and I don't remember I have done anything on Mac, such as OS upgrade, to cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Docker image you're using doesn't have `curl` installed.

Assuming that it's based on Debian or Ubuntu you need to add `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl` to your `Dockerfile`. If it's Alpine then `RUN apk update && apk add curl` should do the trick.

After you rebuild the `mydocker` image (`docker-compose build mydocker`), `docker-compose up` should work (assuming there are no other problems). You can also rebuild and start containers in one go: `docker-compose up --build`.